# Creating a concave dodecahedron using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm trying to create **concave dodecahedron** **using geometry nodes**

[image: img1]

I can create a dodecahedron

[image: img2]

Then add the edges.

[image: img3]

**But how can I collapse the center vertices correctly**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be this:

[image]

Create the base shape as you did, using icosphere and dual mesh.

Extrude individual faces but with zero offset.

Scale this extrusion a bit to make final shape external 'borders'.

Extrude again, this time with (for instance) -0.5 so that the extrusion goes to inverted normals and near the center of the shape.

Scale this extrusion down to a small value.

Use subdivision surface with some edge crease amount.

Shade smooth.

[image]

As Gordon commented, you can harden the edges by adding a subdivide between last 'scale elements' and subdivision surface:

[image]

This will give:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I actually like your solution better than mine ;) The only thing I would add because the reference image is tighter around the corner vertices and not rounded so much, is adding a _Subdivide Mesh_ node between the last _Scale Elements_ and the _Subdivision Surface_ node, then play around with both _Level_ values and the _Edge Crease_ until you like the result. The edges will not be so smooth anymore but still have some "thickness" to it which looks good in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, I've noticed that also. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Playing around with the settings I found there are many options depending on which look you prefer. Without the _Subdivide Mesh_ node for example setting the _Subdivision Surface_ node to _Level_ = 1 and _Edge Crease_ to 0.4 or higher looks good when you add a _Bevel_ modifier to the object. Or instead of beveling, just duplicate the _Subdivision Surface_ node, leave the first at _Level_ = 1 and set the second one to _Level_ = 2 or higher.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, yes, many possibilities...

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I have to admit this is not a perfect solution to get the result of the reference image you are showing, this deals only with the question how to select and collapse the center vertices.

To achieve this, you can use a *Vertex Neighbor* node and plug the *Vertex Count* output into a *Compare* node set to *Greater Than* > 4, because the center vertices have 5 neighbors. The result goes into the *Selection* of a *Set Position* node.

Then you need a *Sample Index* node to get the normals of the points. Scaling these with a *Vector Math* node by a negative value and plugging them into the *Offset* of the *Set Position* node will move the center points inwards.

The only problem with this method, I already added a *Bevel* modifier in the following image (or you could use a *Subdivision Surface* node in the GN modifier as well) to round off the sharp corners, but the outer edges are always pinching in the middle because of the beveled edges going towards the center. That's why my solution is not the best. Maybe someone else finds a better one.

//EDIT: And while I finished my answer, there already is a better one by @lemon ;)

[image: concave dodecahedron]

Answer (score 5):

The results in the other answer look strange to me. I would just merge the vertices after extruding the inset pentagons and use the bevel modifier. Yes, technically that is an additional modifier.

[image: result]

[image: node tree]

Answer (score 2):

To add another piece to the palette of wonderful answers, here's another sharp-edged (and simple) approach that provides a useful topology:

[image]

Here I simply extrude the faces with $0$, then scale them a little to get a certain thickness, extrude them again and move their points to the center.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>